# CSS of the child element not working but parent's css is working fine

Tags: html, css

I am creating a small quiz app. And After answering question in quiz I am showing the progress bar.
But I have styled the progress bar using two div elements, One div parent element and another is child. But when I am applying css on parent div(id = "progressBar") it is working well but child div's (id= "progressBarFull")css is not working.
Please tell me why?

```css
.choice-container{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid rgb(86, 165, 235,0.25);
    background-color: white;

}

.choice-prefix{
    background-color: #56a5eb;
    padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
    color: white;

}

.choice-text{
    padding: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.choice-container:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow: 0.4rem 0.6rem rgba(86, 185, 235, 0.5);
    transform: translate(-0.1rem);
    transition: transform 150ms;
}

.correct{
    background-color: #28a745;
}

.incorrect{
    background-color: #dc3545;
}
/* HUD DISPLAY */

#hud{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.hud-prefix{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.hud-main-text{
    text-align: center;
}

#progressBar{
    width : 20rem;
    height: 3.1rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid #56a5eb;
};

#progressBarFull{
    height: 2.5rem;
    background-color: #56a5eb;
   
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quick Quiz - Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="game.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
            <div id="hud">
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p id= "progressText"class="hud-prefix">
                        
                    </p>
                   <div id="progressBar">
                       <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Score
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                        
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this question?</h2>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Click here for the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKdfi.png)

Comment: you have `};` remove the `;` (closing question as typo)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hello Temani, sorry to bug you, could come around in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript for a sec, I have a small js question.

Comment: @user31782 sorry but JS is not my best, you will find better than me in that room. I only do CSS here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take the semicolons out after the closing braces:

```
#progressBar{
    width : 20rem;
    height: 3.1rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid #56a5eb;
} /* no semicolon here */

#progressBarFull{
    height: 2.5rem;
    background-color: #56a5eb;
   
} /* no semicolon here */
```

For reference check out MDN article on css [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax#css_declaration_blocks). Basically, an unnecessary semicolon after the the terminating curly brace will hamper user agent's parsing of css and the css code following that won't be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a badly placed semicolon after progress Bar. And I would recommend setting height as a percentage.

```css
.choice-container{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid rgb(86, 165, 235,0.25);
    background-color: white;

}

.choice-prefix{
    background-color: #56a5eb;
    padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
    color: white;

}

.choice-text{
    padding: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.choice-container:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow: 0.4rem 0.6rem rgba(86, 185, 235, 0.5);
    transform: translate(-0.1rem);
    transition: transform 150ms;
}

.correct{
    background-color: #28a745;
}

.incorrect{
    background-color: #dc3545;
}
/* HUD DISPLAY */

#hud{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.hud-prefix{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.hud-main-text{
    text-align: center;
}

#progressBar{
    width : 20rem;
    height: 3.1rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid #56a5eb;
}

#progressBarFull{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #56a5eb;
   
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quick Quiz - Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="game.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
            <div id="hud">
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p id= "progressText"class="hud-prefix">
                        
                    </p>
                   <div id="progressBar">
                       <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Score
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                        
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this question?</h2>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```